# Turning on PageCache in yii2 produces strange encoding problem

Tags: php, caching, encoding, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a web portal that I want to add PageCache to. When Activating it, a strange coding appears and after debugging for a while I don't understand the reason since in other projects developed in Yii2 the PageCache works correctly.

```php
[
    'class' => 'yii\filters\PageCache',
    'only' => ['index'],
    'duration' => 300,
    'enabled'=>true,
    'variations' => [
        \Yii::$app->language,
    ],
    'dependency' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\DbDependency',
        'sql' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item',
    ],
],
```

Web config

```php
$config = [
    'id' => 'my-web',
    'language'=>'en',
    'name'=>'My Web',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'defaultRoute' => 'site/index',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_cookiename', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'session-identifier',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

- Ubuntu: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
- Mysql: 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)
- php: 7.0.18

Cache content snippet

```
^_<8b>^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^Cí=ÛvÛ6¶ïý
X<9d><99>$§¦DêfÉ±<9d>ºN<9c>fN.<9e>ÆM<93>^V^VDB^Rl<92>`  Ò<96>ÓéÇôq^^æá¬y<9b><97>®ÕüØÙ^@x'%Q<8a>SÛ­<95>^UY$.^[ØØwÜv6^^¾88~sô^HM^CÇÞûdGüA6v'»^MÂ^[{<9f> øìL       ¶ÔOùè<90>^@#s<8a>}N<82>ÝÆ×Ç<87>Ú Ñ*¦»Ø!»<8d>3JÎ=æ^G^Md27 .ä?§V0ÝµÈ^Y5<89>&^_6^Qui@±­q^SÛd×ØD^N<9e>Q't¢^W½¦¾<89>BN|ù<8c>GðJo¤^@+!<9b>Ü^_k^^ö±<93><81>ýV¼<85><92>¥<8c>^A;%n&ã^[ûô5?^\¿èøüõÁ´£=yr|pö<90><85>m^]^?«^]q|ôz<82>ñ<81>ñTÿö^_úQçéøY<97>¾~wñ¤û^Of|^[|K<9f>^?ó<9a>¾6IçèâÕ³ÿýû^E^?F¦ôéì|w7Óê<9d><80>^F6Ù{é`?xÆÎ¨<8d>4ô^U^Q-6éûÿ¸( öû^?<8d><99>Ë8rÞÿ^GÒ      ßD¾Ìà#z4e.<81>^R/^A^_^NvM¼ÓRõ¥õÛÔ=<85>^B6t^Q»Ì¥<80>º^F<9a>úd¼Û<98>^F<81>·Ýj^YÃvÓè^O<9a><9d>NÓÐ[<8d>Ê²Ø^N<88>ïâ<80>¨²    i,¬     Í!^G^\^FSægð<9c>ö~ÙxZ<84><9b>>õ^BÊ²ã^Tã£^BY<88>Ç¨i&xe.r<98>J^M^D^Y^E<80>RA<9e>ï^?       äË^Kä<84>æ<94>A^]¿ð&:^@(Ø<81>*^A^\^Bê^C<8a>¥^LY$^Z^E5Ldæù<84>ó^XF<4<8d>j^DL^X<9b>ØDã4 Ú^Yñé^XF¥Ð¥Ù<9b>Wçmã^[»ëôÂCþhöôHcìø^_o»Ý§£·§^G§Ó·xüÎÖ^O¼Çæ\<;ü^LÛÔ<82>QkêF¦î~ça»ß3<8c>n{h|qð¨×ë^_^ZíÃîðàáaGï^Z<83>\<85><85><9a>=<9f>yÄ^O.v^[l²m3Á<98><99><9a ......
```

I added several screenshots

[image]

What can be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: This is really weird. Does the same happen to the files when you cache other things (not just the page)?

Comment: Hello @Bizley, That doesn't really happen, I've done a little test. This code `Yii::$app->cache->set("test", "TestData");` produces this cache: `a:2:{i:0;s:8:"TestData";i:1;N;}`

Comment: Is the cache file formatted properly? I mean is it starting with something like `a:2:{i:0;a:9:{s:12:"cacheVersion";i:1;s:9:"cacheData";N;s:7:"content"...`

Comment: Apparently yes, except for the content `a:2:{i:0;a:9:{s:12:"cacheVersion";i:1;s:9:"cacheData";N;s:7:"content";s:7826:"^_<8b>^H^@^@^@^@^@^@ ...`

Comment: Hmm, just a guess - is your server compressing the response, like gziping?

Comment: Is that !!! The truth is that it is the first thing I checked. I disabled the defalted module in apache, but I just remembered that for this project I enabled gzip from yii2 via the ON event and using the ob_x functions (it is possible that collisions with the PageCache filter as it uses those methods). My hosting provider for this project doesn't allow me to enable gzip from the server and that's why I did this fix. Thank you very much for the clues. From this I learn that such arrangements can produce unexpected effects and are best avoided.  Thanks!!!